# How I can return value from select query?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to calculate the distance between two cities. I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_distance_for_cities(fromCityId bigint, toCityId bigint) RETURNS integer LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$

    DECLARE
            fromCityCoords Geometry;
            toCityCoords Geometry;

    BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM geo_cities WHERE geo_cities.id = fromCityId RETURNING coords INTO fromCityCoords;
            SELECT * FROM geo_cities WHERE geo_cities.id = toCityId RETURNING coords INTO toCityCoords;
            SELECT ST_Distance(fromCityCoords, toCityCoords, true)
    END;

    $$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR You "were doing wrong" two things: `returns integer` should be `returns float` and last `select ..` should be `return ..`.

Details:

`RETURN` returns a value from a PL/pgSQL function – you need to use it instead of last `SELECT`. And `st_distance(..)` returns `float` value according http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance.html, so you need `returns float` in your first line.

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_distance_for_cities(fromCityId bigint, toCityId bigint) RETURNS float LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$

    DECLARE
            fromCityCoords Geometry;
            toCityCoords Geometry;

    BEGIN
            SELECT coords INTO fromCityCoords FROM geo_cities WHERE geo_cities.id = fromCityId;
            SELECT coords INTO toCityCoords FROM geo_cities WHERE geo_cities.id = toCityId;
            RETURN ST_Distance(fromCityCoords, toCityCoords, true);
    END;

    $$;
```

Also, this function actually doesn't need PL/pgSQL language and can easily be implemented in plain SQL, with CTE (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
create or replace function calc_distance_for_cities(int8, int8) returns float as $$
  with _from(city_coords) as (
    select coords from geo_cities where geo_cities.id = $1
  ), _to(city_coords) as (
    select coords from geo_cities where geo_cities.id = $2
  )
  select st_distance(_from.city_coords, _to.city_coords)
  from _from, _to;
$$ language sql;
```

Or even w/o CTE:

```
create or replace function calc_distance_for_cities(int8, int8) returns float as $$
  select st_distance(
    (select coords from geo_cities where geo_cities.id = $1),
    (select coords from geo_cities where geo_cities.id = $2)
  );
$$ language sql;
```